# Does the いは in 或いは come from any term, and if so, how is it/was it used?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, phrases

I was curious about いは in 或いは because ある is in its plain form however I can't find anything on it. I don't have any physical dictionary, either nor knowledge of if this is archaic Japanese

Comment: Wiktionary usually contains etymologies. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, [this does seem to contain](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%88%96%E3%81%AF-428581) the 連体形 of ある, followed by an "adverbial particle" (副助詞) い which the etymology doesn't define, and the regular topic particle は.

The etymology explains that the original sense is ある人は ("a certain person"),ある場合は ("in a certain situation"), which is reflected in the first definition:

> 同類の事柄を列挙していろいろな場合のあることを表す 
> Demonstrates the fact that there exists a number of situations, by enumerating a sequence of related possibilities

For this first definition, the dictionary gives the example:

> 或いは歌をうたい、或いは笛を吹く 
> Either singing a song, or playing a flute

So together with the explanation ある場合は "In a certain situation", you can see that the original definition would have meant something like "In one case, singing a song; in another case, playing the flute".

This first definition was generalised to the more abstract notion of "X or Y".

Comment: I didn't check, thank you I made that question pretty late at night

Comment: The Kotobank link confusingly went to [the 回反 entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9B%9E%E5%8F%8D-42840).  I can only think that that must have been a copy-paste goof, so I have edited your answer post to link instead to [the 或は entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%88%96%E3%81%AF-428581), as I think you probably intended.  

Comment: Oops, thanks. But nice to learn a new abbreviation for "rotational symmetry" 